# Read asset file from c++ in flutter through ffi

Tags: flutter, ffi

In flutter project I have data file in asset folder.
I want to read that data file in c++ code.
How can I read file, or what is the path of asset file in c++?

I searched internet, but I can't find solution.

Comment: assets are not part of normal file system: they can be accessed from flutter code only